Error on apply rule 'NotEmpty' for property
I recently upgraded my ASP.NET Web API project to .NET 8. Now I have a lot of warnings related to NJsonSchema.JsonObjectType and NJsonSchema.JsonSchema.get_Type().

Error on apply rule 'NotEmpty' for property 'ResetPasswordRequest.token'
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'NJsonSchema.JsonObjectType NJsonSchema.JsonSchema.get_Type()'.
at ZymLabs.NSwag.FluentValidation.FluentValidationSchemaProcessor.<>c.b__9_6(RuleContext context)
at ZymLabs.NSwag.FluentValidation.FluentValidationSchemaProcessor.ApplyRulesToSchema(SchemaProcessorContext context, IValidator validator)

Library versions:
<PackageReference Include="NSwag.AspNetCore" Version="14.0.7" />
<PackageReference Include="ZymLabs.NSwag.FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="0.6.3" />
<PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="11.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions" Version="11.9.1" />

Thanks for helping
I tried to downgrade library version but not compatible with .NET 8.

well, after upgrading an ASP.NET Web API project to .NET 8, encountering compatibility issues with library versions, specifically NSwag.AspNetCore 14.0.7 and related packages like ZymLabs.NSwag.FluentValidation.AspNetCore 0.6.3 and FluentValidation.AspNetCore 11.3.0, resulting in a missing method exception related to NJsonSchema.JsonSchema.get_Type().

Despite attempting to downgrade library versions, compatibility with .NET 8 remains elusive. Exploring options such as checking for updates, consulting documentation, seeking community support, implementing temporary workarounds, and contacting library maintainers are crucial steps to mitigate the issue while ensuring thorough testing to prevent new complications in the application.

The fundamental issue is an incompatibility between Nswag.FluentValidation and the version of NJsonSchema provided by Nswag, there is an open issue in that repository here
The alpha release fixes the problem. Update ZymLabs.NSwag.FluentValidation.AspNetCore to 0.7.0-alpha0007, clean and rebuild your solution and it will be fixed.

The alpha release removed the warning but the open api specs are not correctly taking the validation rules into account.
